# Fluentd parser plugin

Tags: plugins, fluentd

I am trying to implement a parser plugin for fluentd. Below are the configuration file and the plugin file.

Fluentd config file.

```
<source>
  type syslog
  port 9010
  bind x.x.x.x
  tag flog
  format flog_message
</source>
```

Plugin file

```
module Fluent
  class TextParser
    class ElogParser < Parser
      Plugin.register_parser("flog_message", self)
      config_param :delimiter, :string, :default => " " # delimiter is configurable with " " as default
      config_param :time_format, :string, :default => nil # time_format is configurable
      # This method is called after config_params have read configuration parameters
      def configure(conf)
        if @delimiter.length != 1
          raise ConfigError, "delimiter must be a single character. #{@delimiter} is not."
        end

        # TimeParser class is already given. It takes a single argument as the time format
        # to parse the time string with.
        @time_parser = TimeParser.new(@time_format)
      end

      def call(text)
        # decode text
        # ...
        # decode text 

        yield result_hash
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However the method `call` is not executed after running fluentd. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since v0.12, use `parse` instead of `call`.
docs.fluentd.org was outdated so I just updated the article: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/plugin-development#parser-plugins

Sorry for forget to update the document...